# Create an array whose index are given by a list (not necesseraly regularly spaced)

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to create an array f containing n indices. The label of those indices is stored in a liste of length n, let's call it "list".

So I would like to have something like :

> {f[list[[0]]], f[list[[1]],...}

The point is to affect the f[liste[[i]]] to some values after.

I tried to make a table, but the problem is that the indices cannot be a list from what I have seen (in the sense that they must be regularly spaced).

I also tried to use the array function but I have the same problem, I cannot specify the indices as being a list, it must be a regular spacing.

How can I do it ?

Comment: ... also `Table[f[i],{i, list}]`?

Comment: List indices start with 1 in *Mathematica*, so `list[[0]]` is not valid (it refers to the head, which is `List`).

Comment: Maybe `f /@ list` would work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AssociationMap`.  E.g.,

```
m = AssociationMap[f, {8, 29, 16}]
m[29]  (* f[29] *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a `list` of integers,

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 10]
(*    {5, 8, 8, 2, 6, 2, 3, 7, 7, 5}    *)
```

we can construct the required `{f[list[[1]]], f[list[[2]], ...}` with

```
f /@ list
(*    {f[5], f[8], f[8], f[2], f[6], f[2], f[3], f[7], f[7], f[5]}    *)
```